# How do I edit a system file that seems to be in use?

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I have tried to edit the file

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

but Windows always says that the file is in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be done by running notepad.exe as administrator. The way I do it is by copying the hosts-file into "Copy of hosts", and making the changes in that file. Then I delete the hosts-file (which it will allow for some reason), and rename the copied file to "hosts".

Comment: sorry, I hadnt been to super user for a while :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to run any text editor you use as an administrator and then open the file with it.

Answer (score 1):

Open notepad as an administrator, right click on notepad.exe and select "run as administrator", then use File > Open, navigate to the hosts file.